# How to create a custom button in Android

Tags: android

My name Vung. I just started learning android and have a problem. I want to create a button like in the picture, but I can not know the name of it in the Android Developer. Hope everyone can help me about information which button. Thanks all. Sorry everyone, I write English is not good...

[image]

Comment: It is called FloatingActionButton. Find more info here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

Comment: oh great. Thank you, hopefully soon I can finish my first app

Comment: Vung, your question has been answered by @Blaasd, please accept the answer.

Comment: Sebastian Roth , yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called a *Floating Action Button*. You can read up on it here: [Developers Resource - Floating Action Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html)

and to put one into your layout just add this to your layout xml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

and the android:src can be changed to any icon you want